# Query Pipe Delimited File Not Returning all Records

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am querying a pipe delimited text file using VBA with ADODB. I have tried using both the ACE and JET engines, but the results are the same, and not correct. I saved a "schema.ini" file in the directory telling the engine that the file is pipe delimited. When the query finishes though, I have data that shifted columns and other fields that are blank when I can see the data in the text file. I use the `CopyFromRecordset` method to transfer the results to my workbook. Can anyone see something off in my code? Or has anyone run into this?

My connection string:

```
With Conn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strPath & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
   .Open
End With
```

Value of "strPath":

```
strPath = "H:\Folder\"
```

SQL String:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strFile & ";"
```

Data transfer:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("CashFlows")
        .Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset Rst
        With .Range("a1")
            For i = 0 To Rst.Fields.Count - 1
                .Offset(0, i) = Rst.Fields(i).Name
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End With
```

I have never had issues with ADO (either Ace or Jet) and I use them quite frequently. I have not, however, used them for pipe delimited files before.

Please leave a comment if I am unclear in my explanation, or if you require more code.

**EDIT**
See the two lines out of the pipe delinted text file below. The first line parses normally. The second drops the "651111100" and "654444475". The strangest thing is that these parse totally fine when I open them in Excel directly and use text to columns.

```
08/31/2015|000|000|Recital #5546|0000000012|88885463|123334563
08/31/2015|000|000|DII #7412|651111100|654444475|00000326541
```

I re-checked, and the issue is only that it is dropping columns, not that it is shifting them around. Sorry for any confusion.

**UPDATE**

I did a find/replace in the text file and put in "^" instead of "|". I then tried to run this again and I ran into the same issue!

Comment: Just so I understand correctly: the problem is that the columns start shifting as if there were additional delimiters in the text file (which you do not see)? If so, then the problem is probably not your code but the delimiter and the potential text-qualifier within (if any). The code you provide seems fine to me and compares to the one I use for ages now: https://coastalcoder.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/importing-selected-data-from-csv-file-into-excel-using-vba-ado/

Comment: Your understanding of my problem is correct. The query is also dropping values in columns for certain records that exist in the text file, and doesn't drop those for others. Let me look into text qualifiers and see if that helps at all. I appreciate the response.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the "potential text-qualifier within" may be? Is this something I could diagnose and fix?

Comment: When you have a csv then you have multiple columns within. These columns are separated from one another by a delimiter. Normally this would be a comma `,`. Yet, if one of the columns (to be imported) contains text and this "text column" may even contain a comma then your import gets screwed-up. So, to identify text as such the csv file would identify text as such using a text qualifier. Here is a discussion on MSDN related to SQL (so not really an exact match). But I guess you'll catch the idea better than I can possibly write in a short comment here:

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a92459d-b487-48be-8981-b25d308de915/csv-import-to-a-sql-server-table-with-as-text-qualifier-and-has-in-the-column-data-escaped?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: And here is another post which might help you with your problem: http://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da. And another one: http://ask.metafilter.com/115163/Excel-delimited-text-import-FAIL

Comment: I don't believe it is a text qualifier issue. There are no other pipes in the file, and the rows that parse normal, and those that do not, have no noticeable difference. Please see edit to my question for examples.

Answer (score 0):

While I am still not sure what the problem might, the following is a usable solution:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportTextFile()

Dim lngRowNumber As Long
Dim strImportFile As String
Dim intNextFreeFile As Integer
Dim strOneImportLine As String
Dim arySplitLine As Variant

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

intNextFreeFile = FreeFile
strImportFile = "C:\path\to\the\TextFile.csv"
lngRowNumber = 1

Open strImportFile For Input Access Read As #intNextFreeFile

Do While Not EOF(intNextFreeFile)
    Line Input #intNextFreeFile, strOneImportLine
    arySplitLine = Split(strOneImportLine, "|")
    Sheets(1).Cells(lngRowNumber, 1).Value2 = arySplitLine
    lngRowNumber = lngRowNumber + 1
Loop

Close #intNextFreeFile

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

The test-run on my computer completed the import for one million rows in a 80MB file within 12 seconds.
While I am sure that there are better ways to do this which outperform this solution you might want to give it a try in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew there were other ways to do this, but I need (or greatly prefer) to process the data to a manageable amount before bringing it into Excel.