# data analysis of Excel spreadsheet with 2500000 rows

Tags: excel, bigdata

I have the excel sheet with 2500000 row and size about 7GB,Since we need to compare two excel sheet of such large size.it is not possible even to open such a large excel sheet in laptop/desktop.

Is there any software we can try top open that excel sheet without crashing

Comment: How did the excel sheet get created in the first place?

Comment: it is csv file provided provided to me by E-commerce site

Comment: Currently I am working with it by splitting it but it quite time consuming

Comment: You should be able to automate the splitting process, but if you really want to use Excel it is unavoidable. Any DB will have tools for reading in csv files, so your best bet is some DB.

Comment: I thought is would be. What do you need to do with it / them? Excel probably isn't going to cut it here.

Comment: @JohnColeman currently I am doing it but it is very time consuming

Comment: @Bathsheba actually i cannot upload all 2.5 million product on my server so i need to select some specific products by defining the criteria which i have already done. The problem starts when you update the price next time we should know which product it was so we need to compare old sheet with new sheet so comparing is CPU intensive task.

Comment: You can use something like Python and just a few lines of code to automatically split the file into e.g. 25 files with 100,000 lines each. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20033861/4996248 . Doubtless there are VBScript solutions as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any files of your size. But `Open "C:\tmp\Test.csv" For Input Access Read As #intNextFreeFile` works pretty fast and well on large file. Here is a sample script I wrote for another post some time ago with a performance of 12 seconds for 80MB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563166/query-pipe-delimited-file-not-returning-all-records/35566094#35566094

Comment: Do you have any control over the price update process, or do you just receive a new 7GB file each time? Are the items in the same order in each file (not counting the added or deleted records)?

Comment: we get the file each with old and new products and with updated price